# Can we know that the visit is from the file such as /etc/hosts

Tags: linux, http

when i visit the github.com,and then get a tip like that:

> You have a stale /etc/hosts entry for GitHub.com. Please remove that
>   entry ASAP!

And it confused me, as you can see below:

> 1. Can we get the visit source come form the hosts file and how it works?
> 2. If the answer is NO, i guess that the github.com know it because of the request ip is old, and then the website display the tip.

Sure the /etc/hosts file had been edited. I am in the CHINA, you know.

And thanks to look at this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the only relevant information the website gets is the IP address to which you've connected, and the `Host:` HTTP header saying what domain you are trying to access.

As you say, GitHub is presumably just detecting that you are accessing the wrong IP address, and assuming that you can't be using their real DNS records.